# Delete JetBrains File Associations on Windows

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, microsoft-file-explorer

I used to have 4 JetBrains IDEs: IntelliJ, GoLand, PyCharm, and CLion. However I deleted them because they were npt very light weight and I discovered the greatness of Neovim.

However, whenever I open my file explorer and open a folder with some code, I would see the file name (i.e. `main.go`) and under the File Type section, it would say JetBrains (IDE) File.

For example;

```
File Name --------------- File Type

main.go   --------------- JetBrains GoLand File
```

Also, when I right-click the file, it still shows the "Open With (a JetBrains IDE)" despite them being deleted.

Those two problems are occurring with all 4 JetBrains IDEs I used to have (PyCharm, CLion, GoLand, IntelliJ)

My end goal:

- When right clicking a file, I don't want the option to open it in a JetBrains IDE (because the IDEs are deleted)
- .go / .java / .py (etc) files shouldn't say JetBrains (IDE name) under the File Type section

Comment: I believe this kind of question is better suited for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions). There are many ways how to change the default program that will be used to open files with specific file extension, just google for "change file association windows"

Comment: Generally speaking: https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html -- I personally have used File Types Manager when I needed to edit the file types (to change the file icon, default open action, alter command path etc.)